# awk script to delete single record, not just group of records

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have an awk command that outputs entries absent from $NEWFILE but found in $OLDFILE:

```
awk -F "|" 'NR==FNR{a[$4]++}!a[$4]' $NEWFILE $OLDFILE > $OUTFILE
```

This command works great when all entries for an entity sharing a unique identifier are not found in $NEWFILE. However, it fails when only one entry for the entity, but not all, has been removed from $NEWFILE.

Anyone have a suggestion about how I can tweak this awk command to output all the entries absent from $NEWFILE but found in $OLDFILE, regardless of whether all the entries for an entity are removed?

Sample data: [newfile](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1343706/newfile.csv), [oldfile](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1343706/oldfile.csv)

Comment: Based on your data do you need to key off 4th column or can you key off the 1st?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you want

```
awk -F "|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1 $2 $3 $4]++}!a[$1 $2 $3 $4]' NEWFILE OLDFILE > OUTFILE
```

Since `NEWFILE` don't have the urls present in `OLDFILE` the unique row identifier is the composite of the four first fields. Because `NEWFILE` doesn't have those urls a simple `diff` won't do.

Comment: That's it! I think it could probably be shortened to: `awk -F "|" 'NR==FNR{a[$2 $4]++}!a[$2 $4]' NEWFILE OLDFILE > OUTFILE` but yes that's it! Thank you!

Comment: @user981023: That might be so. Wasn't sure which assumptions to make about the rest of your dataset from the limited example data present. Feel free to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Well, I was thinking that since the columns $1 and $3 always match $4, $2 is what makes the entry unique. So if $2 AND $4 match, you can delete with confidence. Is that correct?

Comment: @user981023: I didn't notice that, but yeah, you're right. That's a safe assumption given that connection.

Answer (score 2):

Short and sweet: Use `diff`. You can `diff oldfile newfile | grep '^< ' | cut -b3-` to limit the output to what you want.

Comment: `diff` doesn't work for his case, since `OLDFILE` has an url field for each line that `NEWFILE` doesn't. Your short and sweet command amounts to `cat newfile`.

Comment: so we might want to remove that first, getting something along the lines of `sed oldfile -e 's/|[^|]*$//' | diff - newfile | grep '^< ' | cut -b3-`

Comment: The problem I keep running into with `diff` is that it keeps overwriting the URLs in the final column of the oldfile, and I need them preserved.

Comment: This is going to be a complicated task, but if you need it that specifically, you can 1) stay with diff and add another kludge to glue the urls on again after diffing (like `| while read line; do grep ^"$line" oldfile` (only works if your lines are still unique after removing the urls), or 2) use perl or python, or anything where you can define the compare function yourself and make up the diffing functionality yourself

Comment: I agree that `diff` is very handy, and I use it daily, but in my opinion it's not the right tool for this specific task.

Answer (score 0):

AWK is a line by line interpreter that's reason for only one line being removed and others being in place. You can do two things:

- If you can, filter with an expression which is common to lines.
- For each line of newfile, run a for loop which will iterate oldfile and do operation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Must you use `awk`?  May we simply employ `join` instead, which is really what you're doing here, no?

```
$join -v2 -t'|' -j4 <(sort -t'|' -k4 newfile) <(sort -t'|' -k4 oldfile ) |tee outfile
P-1-01541|22|Professor|University of Alabama at Birmingham|http://www.uab.edu/
P-1-01541|22|Short-Term Scholar|University of Alabama at Birmingham|http://www.uab.edu/
```

This of course assumes you're joining on column 4, and like most rudimentary joins that you don't want to re-iterate, it must be sorted first.